# Telegram API returning HTML instead of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot to report fail2ban bans. It's very simple and dirty, written hastily, but it can be used to report any message to a single telegram user:

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
var fs = require('fs');

var store = {
    get: function (key) {
        return fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/' + key, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    },

    set: function (key, value) {
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/' + key, value, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
    }
};

var token = store.get('token');
var args = process.argv.slice(2);

if (args.length == 0) {
    console.error('No mode specified');
    process.exit(0);
}

TelegramBot.prototype.unregisterText = function (regexp) {
    for (var i = 0; i < bot.textRegexpCallbacks.length; ++i) {
        if (bot.textRegexpCallbacks[i].regexp.toString() == regexp) {
            bot.textRegexpCallbacks.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }           
    }
};

fs.appendFileSync(__dirname + '/logs', 
    '[' + (new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')) + '] '
        + args.join(' ') + '\n', 
    { encoding: 'utf-8' });

switch (args[0]) {
    case 'setup':
        var bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });
        var step = 'none';

        bot.onText(/\/setup/, function (msg, match) {
            var fromId = msg.from.id;
            step = 'setup-started';
            bot.sendMessage(fromId, 'Starting setup. Please enter the verification key.');

            bot.onText(/(.+)/, function (msg, match) {
                if (step == 'setup-started') {
                    var key = match[1];
                    var verification = store.get('key');
                    if (key == verification) {
                        store.set('owner', msg.from.id);
                        step = 'verified';
                        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'Correct. Setup complete.');
                    } else {
                        step = 'none';
                        bot.unregisterText(/(.+)/);
                        bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, 'Wrong. Setup aborted.');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        break;

    case 'report':
        var bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: false });
        var owner = store.get('owner');
        var subject = args[1];

        if (subject == 'message') {
            var message = args.slice(2).join(' ');
            bot.sendMessage(owner, message);
        } else if (subject == 'file') {
            var content = fs.readFileSync(args[2], { encoding: 'utf-8' });
            bot.sendMessage(owner, content);
        }

        break;

    default:
        console.error('Unrecognized mode', args[0]);
        break;
}
```

On my developer machine it works fine. I invoke:

```
node bot.js report message whatever message i want
```

And I correctly received "whatever message i want" on telegram. However, once I gitted it on my digitalocean vps, it no longer worked. It turns out the problem is with the telegram library:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Error parsing Telegram response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bots: An introduction for developers</title>
    ...
```

Which apparently returns an html page instead of json... I also tried to contact the same endpoint (api.telegram.org/bothash/sendMessage) with curl on my vps and it returned json (with an error message because i didnt send any parameters, but still json).

I cannot fathom why this happens. Any help?

Comment: Just to make sure; you did a `npm install` on your remote vpn, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have the node-telegram-bot-api

Comment: You would have it, if you ran it on your local environment, then git added even the node modules folder, commited it and checked it out remotely. And this indeed would explain this strange behavior..

Comment: node_modules are not to be versioned. best practices have that you only commit package.json and other similar configuration files. And anyway, even if it was, no it would not explain this behaviour...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like either you don't have a file with token on your VPN or the token is incorrect.

You can check it by yourself:

When you make a request to `api.telegram.org/{token}/sendMessage`, and `{token}` is incorrect, it redirects you to [this page](https://core.telegram.org/bots), which responds with HTML you've mentioned in your question.

So you have to debug a behavior of your `store.get` and `store.get` functions along with files and tokens to make sure you are using a correct one.

Also, I'd recommend to run `bot.getMe()` before using any other Telegram API methods to ensure you specified a correct bot token.

Comment: I already checked that I have a token. The token exists and is valid. I compared it with the one on my developer machine and it's exactly the same. I'll try getMe()

Comment: Turns out, there was a newline character at the end of token, even after I removed it in the token file. A trim() solved the problem u.q